# Bash script: change to a directory with special chars

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that goes through my music collection and downloads missing covers. The problem I have is that I can't cd to some directories which has '&' '(' and other characters.

The relevant part of the script is copied below:

```
IFS="\n"
IFS="$(printf '\n\t')"
for i in `find $1 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -i -q "^cover\.(jpg|png)$"' ';' -print`; do
        echo "===="
        echo "processing: " $i
        cd "${i}"
        #download_cover $i
        echo "++++"
done
```

If I run this script for those directories I get this output:

```
cd 'media/FlacMusic/Mumford & Sons/Sigh No More'
devel/get_album_cover.sh: line 22: cd: media/FlacMusic/Mumford & Sons/Sigh No More: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [Escape Characters, delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-quoting.html)

Comment: You might also want to read [why you shouldn't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm not trying to parse ls output but the find one, as I understand from the line above. But I can even use another approach. What do you suggest to do id I need to cd through some directories with weird filenames?

Comment: it turned out I found a solution, using the variable without braces the variable. I'm quite sure I've tried it before, but maybe I was trying to cd inside a function, passing the path as a parameter. I don't remember. anyway if I use `cd "$i"` the script runs just fine

Comment: Or, you can use `sed` to process ${i}, so that each " " is replaced by "\ ".

Comment: Also, do you know you can answer your question and accept your own solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is the OP's solution. It was posted as an edit to the question, it should be an answer instead.

> I took out the braces around the variable and the script runs just fine.
>
> ```
> cd "$i"
> ```